# UNIQUE constraint failed using room

Tags: android, android-room

I have a Room database with an insert query and auto generated Primary Key but I still face this error
**android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed**

this is the Entity class , in real code I implemented Parcelable but I think it doesn't affect so I didn't put it

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes")
public class Note implements Parcelable {
    public static final String ID = "id";
    @Ignore
    public final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "header")
    private String header = "";
    @ColumnInfo(name = "body")
    private String body = "";
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    private String date = "";
    
    public Note() {}

    public Note(String body){
        this.body=body;
        setDate();
    }
    public Note(String header, String body) {
        this.header = header;
        this.body = body;
        setDate();
    }
    public Note(String header ,String body,String date){
        this(header,body);
        setDate(date);
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setDate() {
        Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm");
        date = sm.format(currentTime);
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return header.isEmpty() && body.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Note{" +
                " \"header\":" + header +
                ",\n\"body\":" + body + "\n" +
                "}";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        Note o = (Note) other;
        return id == o.id;
    }

    public boolean equalsIgnoreDate(Note other) {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return header.equals(other.getHeader()) && body.equals(other.getBody());
    }
}
```

this is the Dao

```
@Dao
public abstract class NoteDao {
    @Query("select id,header,date from notes")
    public abstract List<Note> getAll();

    @Insert
    public abstract Long insert(Note note);

    @Delete
    public abstract void delete(Note note);

    @Update
    public abstract void update(Note note);

    @Query("select*from notes where id=:id")
    public abstract Note getNoteById(long id);
}
```

Comment: How did you solve this? I am getting this error(crashlytics) from live apps but not able to reproduce the issue.